# Migrate cassandra from data centre to cassandra on AWS

Tags: cassandra

I have 4 nodes cassandra cluster running on data centre. We want to move from data centre to AWS. After internal discussion , we decided to move cassandra data from data centre to newly created cassandra cluster on AWS. Data size is around 150 gb. What is the best load/dump approach should be taken for this. Cassandra version is pretty old (1.2.9)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- if you have connectivity between your DC and AWS, then just add the AWS as 2nd [data center into existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html), replicate all data, and then [decommission the old data center](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html) - with this approach you can even avoid downtime if your applications first will work with old DC, then you switch them to AWS, etc.
- you can copy the application data as-is to nodes - but this will require an additional work when setting up your cluster, like, explicitly set initial tokens, pre-create schema, etc.
- you can copy the SSTables to AWS, and load them into cluster with [sstableloader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsSStables/toolsBulkloader.html) - but this will stream all your data to nodes, so it may fastest way...

Comment: Its fine to have downtime for my application.So I am skipping first step as of now. We are using old version of cassandra which is 1.2.9. I am not sure whether sstableloader has support for it or not. Can you please let me know details about 2nd point where we can copy data as it is. Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: sstableloader should exist in 1.2.x...

Comment: regarding the 2nd item - the idea is you setup the destination cluster with the same token distribution as in your original cluster - you need to have the same `initial_token` as on original cluster (if you're using vnodes then it could be cumbersome). After you do this, create keyspaces/tables with the same structure as your source cluster. Then copy files from your source cluster into corresponding folders of nodes with matching initial_token of destination cluster. after that restart nodes, or use `nodetool refresh` (not sure that it was in 1.2.9) to make data visible

Comment: but i think that sstableloader approach will be the fastest....

Comment: I am trying to find complete set up of steps for 2nd approach (copy the application data as-is to nodes). Do you have complete set of steps for sample data ? Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: No, I don’t have such description available publicly. I suggest just to stream data